# Display tables with static text and images in iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am at a loss of how to display tables (think header, rows, cells) filled with static information (text, images, lists) in an iOS app. `UITableView` does not accomplish this as far as I have found.

Outside of this environment I would simply building an html table, fill it with the content and serve it to the user.

Since I'm new to iOS development, I'm just lost. I have considered creating web pages, including them in the app and pointing a `UIWebView` to them but I haven't tested this out yet since it seems like a hack.

In a nutshell, how can I take what would essentially be an HTML table and display it in an iOS app. I'm not necessarily looking for a step by step hold my hand answer, but some indication of how this situation is normally resolved.

EDIT: Last thought, do people just insert images of tables like this? Again, seems like a hack.

Answer (score 0):

You have to options:

1) Use a UITableViewController and fill it with static cells with your own content, designed in Storyboard or programmatically.

2) You can use the UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDatasource methods. Those methods will help you on creating dynamic tables and setup them by code. You'll be able to update your content and some other stuff.

Check this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html

If you need more information, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

There are usually two approaches, either there's a webservice like (JSON,XML..) where you can parse the content and populate them in your UITableView, but this must be provided by the website administrator. Or by HTML Parsing which you may find a lot of tutorials out there explaining how to parse content of html into UITableView, but the risk here is that if it happens and the tags change or any of the structure changes, your app would crash.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a way to create a 2d-matrix, then you're probably better of using a `UICollectionView` then an `UITableView`.

This repository hosts a decent starting point: [github.com/brightec/CustomCollectionViewLayout](https://github.com/brightec/CustomCollectionViewLayout)

[image: CustomCollectionViewLayout]

Answer (score 0):

If its really static, you can create static `tableCiewCells` and drag and drop labels, imageviews. etc into them and then create IBOutlets if you need.

Check out [this](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-static-table-view-storyboard/) link. Cheers